# Default output of input

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I'm trying to make a sample code that extracts first name from a full name.

If my input is not string or simply press just enter, it will print out enter valid name.

But no matter what I type, it just prints out normal outcome.

Also if I type nothing, it just makes an error.

How can I solve this?

```
name = input("Enter your full name (end to stop): ")


def print_first_name():

    if type(name) == str:
        name.split()
        first = name.split()[0]
        last = name.split()[-1]
        print('Your first name is: ', first)

    elif name == 'end':
        break

    else:
        print('You must enter at least your first name!')


print_first_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = input("Enter your full name: ")

def print_first_name():
    if len(name) > 0:
        first = name.split()[0]
        if first.isalpha():
            print('Your first name is: ', first)
        else:
            print("Enter a valid name")
        last = name.split()[-1]
            
    else:
        print('You must enter at least your first name!')


print_first_name()
```

The condition you wrote (type(name)==str) will always be true

we cant use break outside a loop. (in your case, there was no loop at all, so u cant use break)

if you enter nothing, it gives an error because the line

```
name.split()[0]
```

if name="", (which means an empty string), name.split() gives an empty list

In a empty list, there will be no element at index 0, so it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

The input is always string, so you can use a array or list to store 0 -> 9 numbers (The `str` one). If there is a number in input, it'll print something.
You can use `''` to describe that input is empty

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to Python, so I don't understand the array part. How can I store numbers?

Comment: I'll say about list one because is built-in (Array is provided by [NumPy](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/default.asp)). A list is like a chest where is store multiple variables.
Exp:
`a = []` (empty list)
`a = [<value>, <value>]` (list with value)
Note: List can store **more** than 2 item.
Read more at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `if type(name) == str:`, then even when you type `end` as input, this condition is satisfied and the if block is executed and hence code flow never goes to the elif block.

You can put your else condition first and then the if condition:

```py
    if name == 'end':
        #do whatever

    elif type(name) == str:
        #do whatever

    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems, marked with comments below:

```
name = input("Enter your full name (end to stop): ")

# Generally you should pass a variable to a function
# or define the variable inside the function, rather 
# than using a global variable (name). It's not clear
# which part of the code you want to isolate in a
# function in this example, so it's probably simplest
# not to use a function at all.
def print_first_name():
    # The next test will always be True, so the else 
    # and elif parts will never run.
    # You probably want a test for non-empty 
    # strings with only alphabetic characters instead
    if type(name) == str:
        # the next line creates a list of the parts of
        # name (if possible) but doesn't store it 
        # anywhere, so it has no effect.
        name.split()
        # the next two lines will fail if name is 
        # an empty string
        first = name.split()[0]
        last = name.split()[-1]
        print('Your first name is: ', first)

    # the next block needs to be moved earlier to
    # make sure it is tested before you try to extract
    # the names
    elif name == 'end':
        # break cannot be used inside a function
        # even if the function is called in a loop
        break
    else:
        print('You must enter at least your first name!')


print_first_name()
```

Here's a version that fixes these problems:

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter your full name (end to stop): ")

    # check this first, to avoid treating as a name
    if name == 'end':
        break
    # check whether name contains any digits or is empty
    elif name.isalpha() and name != "":
        name_parts = name.split()
        first = name_parts[0]
        last = name_parts[-1]
        print('Your first name is: ', first)
    else:
        print('You must enter at least your first name!')
```

Answer (score 0):

input() defaults to returning a string type. It looks like you're trying to sanitize the input by making sure the input is a string of letters, and also has a length > 0  before running.

You would probably be served by flipping out

```
if type(name) == str:
```

with something that checks both for a non-zero AND alpha only. so something like

```
if name.isalpha() and len(name) > 0:
    {conditional code here...}
```